# How to generate incremental builds with git / jenkins C#

Tags: git, jenkins, incremental-build

New job is migrating from CVS to GIT ( Yey!! )

Problem is - we used to generate our release packages in a incremental manner - we used modified file date on CVS to figure out which projects would need to be recompiled and only generated those packages - the reason for that was to reduce the size of new releases ( our project is pretty huge to be easily distributed ).

When I clone the directory through jenkins to build, all the files have the same modified date, so the old approach is a no-go. Though about doing it using the git log, but then I might loose a commit that was done earlier than my last build, but only merged after it.

I do believe that this should be a simple and common problem to have to solve, but I have never really worked with Dev ops - I am just a Dev that thought that the way we are trying to do this is not a smart way.

Comment: I have the same question @Remo , I have a hybrid build that produces a number of artifacts, but takes 11 minutes to run. I want to change it to incremental and then cache the objects, and then just restore the workspace and check out any commits and rebuild. Problem is that checking out into workspace the last full build objects takes time. Has anyone got a blog or how-to on some of the fundamentals I need to follow here? I am taking the approach of a pipeline groovy script, but no idea if this will be time efficient yet.

Comment: By hybrid build, I mean I'm producing packages for 2 linux distros, a Mac and a Windows set of binaries. And I hope to decompose those as I go along using pipelines to parallel build individual components where possible. I then want to do a nightly full-build, archive it each day, and then have incremental builds pull the full-nightly artifact into the workspace as the starting point and just "playback" commits on top of the commit the nightly built with. Hopeing it will be faster, it's all very much a customized problem or is it very common?